# Django How to Add Base Form Template Context Processer

Tags: django, django-templates

In my navbar I have a newsletter button that pops up a modal. In the modal there is a form that I can use to get the email and do some form manipulation. Since this modal is in the base template, the form must be available for all urls. I have added 'blog.context_processors.email_form' in the settings, and a context_processer.py file with the below info:

```
from .forms import EmailForm


def email_form(request):
    return {
         'email_form': EmailForm()
    }
```

In my forms.py I have:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Email


class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='',
                             widget=forms.EmailInput
                             (attrs={'id': 'emailInput', 'class': 'article-search',
                                     'placeholder': 'Enter yorffreur email here...', 'type': 'text'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ['email']

    def clean_email(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = Email.objects.filter(email__iexact=email)

        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email already exists.')

        return email
```

In the base templates I have included the form as {{ email_form }}. But I do not know where to add the form manipulation. Usually I add it in the views but I'm new so I am an unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a view wherever you want that will receive the form and validate it then redirect to a page that will confirm the success of the subscription.

You just have to use the `action` property of the `<form>` tag to specify which view will handle the form :

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'handle_newsletter' %}">
```

Then in your view, something like this :

```
def handle_newsletter(request):
    form = EmailForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
         return redirect('subscription_confirmation')  # you would need to create this view
    # An error occurred
    print(form.errors)
    return redirect('home')
```

Don't forget to update your `urls.py` with the appropriate view names.

Comment: Okay I still have a few more doubts. In the view, how should I manipulate the form? Since I have used it as email form in context processor, I am unfamiliar with how to manipulate it in the view. I am okay with normal forms though. Question 2 is in the action form tag, do I have to add any template stuff or just the name of the view?

Comment: def email_submit(request, template):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # validation stuff 

    else:
        form = EmailForm()

    context = {
        'email_form': form,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)

And in the template I just did action="email_submit" but it says Reverse for 'email_submit' not found. 'email_submit' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: I've edited my answer to illustrate with an example of implementation

Comment: thanks man, it worked! For the URLs, I created:

 path('newsletter', views.handle_newsletter, name='handle_newsletter'). The function works but is this proper practice or the URL is off?

Comment: What do you mean by the URL is off ? Yeah I always use it like this, I find it really useful to be able to name each route and then if I want to update the URL path, I can without having to change everywhere in templates

Comment: Oh Im just asking if the way I wrote the URL is not conventionally correct. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Ah okay, no it's alright like you've done ! You're welcome ;)